# How do I imitate having two list of items, while having only one list in css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Basically I have an `<ul>` with some `<li>` inside, from which I'm trying to create 2 separate blocks:

```
<ul>
    <li class="group1">List 1</li>
    <li class="group1">List 1</li>
    <li class="group2">List 2</li>
    <li class="group2">List 2</li>
    <li class="group1">List 1</li>
    <li class="group2">List 2</li>
    <li class="group1">List 1</li>
    <li class="group1">List 1</li>
    <li class="group2">List 2</li>
    <li class="group2">List 2</li>
    <li class="group2">List 2</li>
    <li class="group1">List 1</li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to achieve here, is to basically have 2 blocks side by side separated based on the groupN classname

Note: I do not want to use any javascript for this

Comment: Actually it kinda does.

Comment: I could get my hands dirty, but was wondering if I can keep it clean by doing it with raw css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS-Grid can do that

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.group1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.group2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group1">List 1</li>
  <li class="group1">List 1</li>
  <li class="group2">List 2</li>
  <li class="group2">List 2</li>
  <li class="group1">List 1</li>
  <li class="group2">List 2</li>
  <li class="group1">List 1</li>
  <li class="group1">List 1</li>
  <li class="group2">List 2</li>
  <li class="group2">List 2</li>
  <li class="group2">List 2</li>
  <li class="group1">List 1</li>
</ul>
```

Note: `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` is not strictly necessary as the grid will have implicit columns based on where you tell each class to be.